# Android SQLite returns nothing when called via adb shell, but when inside adb it works

Tags: android, sqlite, shell, adb

I have a rooted Android phone and I want to access the database of an application through `adb`, say, in every minute.

So, when I go into adb shell via `adb` command and inside the shell, I execute the SQL command, it works and I get the output:

```
# echo "select id,timestamp from record_table ORDER BY id DESC limit 1;" | sqlite3 /data/data/APPLICATION/databases/record_database                                                                                                                            
99|1599214373234
```

However, when doing this directly via

```
$ adb shell "su -c echo \"select id,timestamp from record_table ORDER BY id DESC limit 1;\" | sqlite3 /data/data/APPLICATION/databases/record_database"
```

I got nothing back on my terminal. (I guess, there is no problem with escaping the quotes as it would drop an error and I also tried several other ways to define this command)

I suppose there should be something with the stdout/stderr of adb, but after doing this

```
adb shell su -c setprop log.redirect-stdio true
```

It still not works.

Anyone did ever encounter this issue?

Comment: I tried also to redirect out to /data/local/tmp/random_file, but that file's content is also empty

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, got it working. More sophisticated character escaping was necessary :D
Command did not go through sqlite3, so using single quotes solved the issue.
Sorry for posting...

Correct command is:

```
adb shell su -c "echo 'select * from record_table ORDER BY id DESC limit ${N};' | sqlite3 $DB_PATH"
```